# Unable to send mail with text and html at once using EmailMessage & smtplib in python

Tags: python-3.x, html-email, smtplib

I am trying to send mail using EmailMessage and smtplib. I can successfully send normal text as body. But when html with embeded images is added as msg.add_alternative(html) I only receive html part and not the text part in the mail. And text part(body) is visible in the inbox but not when I open the mail. Below is the part of the code I am working with.

```py
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.header import Header
from email.utils import formataddr, make_msgid

SENDER_MAIL = "sender@email.com"
SENDER_PASSWORD = "sender password"
SENDER_TITLE = "sender title"
recipient = "recipient@email.com"

subject = "This is the subject."
body = "This is the body."
html_string = """
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                    <title>email</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <td>
                                        <img width="138" height="138" src="cid:{dp_cid}" alt="">
                                    </td>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <tbody>
                    <table>
                <body>
            """

def compose_mail(subject, body, html):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = formataddr((str(Header(SENDER_TITLE, 'utf-8')), SENDER_MAIL))
    msg['To'] = recipient

    # ================= Attach plain text as body
    msg.set_content(body, subtype="plain", charset='utf-8')

    # ================= Load images to the html
    dp_cid = make_msgid()

    msg.add_alternative(html.format(dp_cid=dp_cid[1:-1]), subtype='html')

    with open("Images/dp.png", "rb") as img:
        msg.get_payload()[1].add_related(img.read(), "image", "png", cid=dp_cid)

    # ================= Send mail
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('server', port)
    server.login(SENDER_MAIL, SENDER_PASSWORD)
    server.send_message(msg)
    server.quit()
    print("Mail sent.")

compose_mail(subject, body, html_string)
```

Comment: Receiving of either mime parts is dependent on the email client. Some can be configured to receive only text versions. By default if you are sending both mime types, HTML get first preference.

Comment: @Syfer, Ok, but it's possible with MIMEMultipart but not with EmailMessage. When I was searching for my solution most of forums suggested EmailMessage instead of MIMEMultipart for sending mails in python. So should I go with MIMEMultipart or not?